# What's faster, an inline function call or a hashmap lookup

Tags: c++, performance, sorting, data-structures

Say I have a class `ClassToSort` which I need to sort with `std::sort()` based on the values of `val` and `secondVal` (in ascending order of `(val * 100) + secondVal`).

```
class ClassToSort {
  private:
    int val;
    long int secondVal;
    int id;

  public:
    inline const int getVal() const { return val; }
    inline const long int getSecondVal() const { return secondVal; }
    inline const int getID() const { return id; }
};

std::vector<ClassToSort*> objs;
```

Now, I have two ways to sort it, either precompute the value of `(val * 100) + secondVal` and store it in an `std::unordered_map<int, long> valMap` and refer to this map while sorting, or make function calls to `getVal()` and `getSecondVal()` each time while sorting (this will cause the number of function calls to double). Here are the two options:

```
std::sort(objs.begin(), objs.end(),
         [&](const ClassToSort* first, const ClassToSort* second) {
          return valMap[first->getID()] < valMap[second->getID()];
         });
```

and

```
std::sort(objs.begin(), objs.end(),
         [](const ClassToSort* first, const ClassToSort* second) {
          return (first->getVal() * 100 + first->getSecondVal()) <
                 (second->getVal() * 100 + second->getSecondVal());
         });
```

It is clear that the second option will not only call getter functions for each object twice, but also do the same computation twice. Intuitively, I would think that for large number of inputs, hashtable lookup would be faster than when the number of function calls is more, along with recalculation. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: You should measure it and let us know. When it comes to performance, there is rarely a "best solution". Rather, it depends strongly on the data and it's layout, the system it's running on, the implementation being used, and many other variables.

Comment: the only valid answer to "what is faster?" is: measure.

Comment: Those `inline` declarations are redundant - the functions are inline without them.

Comment: Well, I could measure it, but then I won't know why one is faster.

Comment: btw why do you care? Actually you should measure even before asking yourself "what is faster?"

Comment: @tobi303 I care because I would like to use the faster algorithm

Comment: did you profile your real case and identified this part as a hot spot? If not, write code to be readable and let the compiler do the optimizations

Comment: @pinbox You may be interested in https://godbolt.org/ to inspect the resulting assembly generated. It can help understand why some solutions are faster than others.

Comment: based on the comments and the influx of downvotes, it seems to me like any of the implementations could be faster, based on many variables mentioned by @FrançoisAndrieux. I doubt I'll get a meaningful answer here, time to hit the books

Comment: @pinbox No, time to hit the profiler. Profile it, see which one is faster, _then_ ask here if you can't figure out why by yourself.

Comment: tip: I am pretty sure that you wont get downvoted that much if you measure (dont forget to turn on compiler optimizations), present the results and ask "why is A so much faster than B?"

Comment: @tobi303 thanks for the tip! I haven't been that active in the SO community long enough to know what kind of questions would be downvoted

Comment: dont worry too much about votes ;)

Comment: Is `secondVal` ever larger than `100`?

Comment: @Walter in my case no, but why does it matter?

Comment: It does matter, since then you only need to get `secondVal` if the `val`s are identical: `return first->getVal()<second->getVal() || (first->getVal()==second->getVal() && first->getSecondVal()<second->getSecondVal());`

Comment: @Walter you're right, that would reduce it from 5 operations (2 additions, 2 multiplications and a comparison) to 2 operations (2 comparisons), thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct functions calls are inlined automatically most of the time.

The complexity in your example isn’t that you call »the getter« twice but that you do your calculation several times – for all comparisons with a specific element.

Using `unordered_map` you also have to create the hash table first.

Have a look at [these](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fccace6896fef0ef) benchmarks.

Using the members directly vs a getter function makes no difference.
The hash lookups are 10 times as slow as doing the calculation for each comparison.
If you have to sort several times it may be useful to keep the calculated value (cache) by storing it as a pair (as a cheaper alternative to a hashmap).

Using pointers to your class instead of values may change the performance (for the worse) but it shouldn’t change the observed differences.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I profiled both cases and found that for smaller inputs, using hash table has a large overhead and is significantly slower. Direct function calls are indeed inlined but just wanted to make it explicit. For my purposes, I don't except the number of inputs to be more than 500, so I might be better off without the hash table.